# How to findout second record for every first record in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a requirement where i have to count the stanno which are mising in orderwise like 182,182 i have to take count of those with dates

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|id     |stanno| dates              
| 1     |  181 | 2019-01-01               
| 2     |  183 | 2019-01-01           
| 3     |  184 | 2019-02-01           
| 4     |  185 | 2019-02-01           
| 5     |  186 | 2019-02-03           
| 6     |  187 | 2019-08-09           
|_7 _ _ |_ 189_| 2019-08-10
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can join this table with itself and use join rule where value must be equal to value + 1, like this:

```
SELECT t1.stanno+1 AS missing
FROM test_table t1
LEFT JOIN test_table t2 ON t1.stanno+1 = t2.stanno
WHERE t2.stanno IS NULL
;
```

Result must looks like this:

```
+---------+
| missing |
+---------+
|     182 |
|     188 |
|     190 |
+---------+
```